# MYSQL LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax Error - where is it wrong?

Tags: mysql, syntax, load-data-infile

where is the Synthax error here?

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'mysqlout_back.txt' 
INTO TABLE temp (user,category,site,tld,ip,updated,date) 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' ;
```

Comment: What does the error message say?

Comment: it says there is a SYNTAX error (6400) near FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n', however I dont know where that should be

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you only want to load the data in specific columns, the go to the end:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'mysqlout_back.txt' 
INTO TABLE temp FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
(user,category,site,tld,ip,updated,date) ;
```

---

EDIT, regarding the file location in your comments:

> The server uses the following rules to locate the file:
>
> - If the file name is an absolute path name, the server uses it as given.
> - If the file name is a relative path name with one or more leading components, the server searches for the file relative to the server's
>     data directory.
> - If a file name with no leading components is given, the server looks for the file in the database directory of the default database.

See the [MySQL ref](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Comment: Ah thanks. But now I get this error: ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'concrast'@'%. However, I have set the rights that the user concrast can import data. Now I had to set global rights for the user and it works. However, now I get this error: Can't get stat of '[path]/mysqlout_back.txt' (Errcode: 13)

Comment: had to copy file to database directory. Works now, Great!